# ActionCommand and Vector

Tags: java

I am trying to retrieve a list of tables in a database and store them in a `Vector`. I then wish to iterate through the Vector. If the Button action command matches one of the elements (ie actioncommand = dbTable) I retrieve data from the selected table elsewhere in the code.

So far I am able to get a list of tables into a Vector of Vectors. However when I execute my if statement, I get no results. I would appreciate if someone guide me on how to solve the problem. Thank you.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    String actionCMD = e.getActionCommand();
    for (Iterator itr = allTables.iterator();itr.hasNext();){
        if(actionCMD.toUpperCase().equalsIgnoreCase(            
                 itr.next().toString().toUpperCase())){
            dbTable = ationCMD;
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void getDBTables(){
    try {
          DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
          ResultSet resultset = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
          this.rs = resultset;
          allTables = new Vector();
          while (rs.next()) {              
              tableList = new Vector();
              tableList.addElement(rs.getString(3));
              allTables.addElement(tableList);
          }// end while
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(TableModel.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } finally{
         if (rs != null)  {
            try {
                rs.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Menu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
         }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `Vector`'s to the `allTables` Vector (instead of directly adding the `String`'s) and therefore it will allways fail the comparison. Eliminate `tableList`.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using `Vector` in new code unless you have a specific purpose (multithreaded synchronization), and the Iterator construct as well is not necessary (but can still be used). You're also calling `toUpperCase` but then also calling `equalsIgnoreCase`.

That being said, as it is you're getting a `Vector` via `itr.next()` then calling `toString()` on it. That's never going to match. You need to iterate through the `String`s in that `Vector`. You also need a way to break out of the outer loop once you've matched

```
boolean found = false;
for (Iterator itr = allTables.iterator();itr.hasNext() && !found;) {
    Vector v = itr.next();
    for (Iterator itr2 = v.iterator(); itr2.hasNext() && !found;) {    
        if(actionCMD.equalsIgnoreCase(itr2.next().toString())) {
            dbTable = ationCMD;
            found = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The modern way to accomplish this would be to use an `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`

```
List<List<String>> allTables;
...
allTables = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
...
tableList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And your loop looks like:

```
for (List<String> tables : allTables)
{
    for (String s : tables)
    {
        if (actionCMD.equalsIgnoreCase(s)) // Why up-case? You're ignoring case
        {
            dbTable = ationCMD;
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found)
        break;
}
```

You could also still go with the iterator here to eliminate the `if (found)` statement, or use the `List.get(index)` method to achieve the same results, using a counter. IMHO the above is just easier to read.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick responses. i am happy to say that stackoverflow is my main resource for finding answers relating to java. you solved my problem. i used ArrayList. there is one problem remaining though and that is that when i click on buttons few times in a short time, i get this error " message from server: "Too many connections"" despite closing connection after each event!

Comment: @arjang27 - you're closing your result set in the code above, but that error is talking about connections to the db itself. I don't know where you're opening the connection (the `conn` object) but it sounds like you're doing it multiple times without closing previous ones.